# Connecting Prisma to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, prisma

I am trying to connect Prisma to an SQL Database in Azure. I noticed that my Azure SQL Database connection string does not look anything like the connection strings in the Prisma getting started document.

```
Server=tcp:mufdatabase.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=muf;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=muf;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Whereas Prisma lists MS SQL Server connection string example as

```
sqlserver://localhost:1433;initial catalog=sample;user=sa;password=mypassword;
```

I thought Azure SQL Database was just an SQL Server so why would the connection strings be so different? Does Prisma support Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it does according to [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/sql-server)

If we look at your line, the prisma configuration should look like this

```
sqlserver://mufdatabase.database.windows.net:1433;initialCatalog=muf;integratedSecurity=false;username={your username};password={your password};trustServerCertificate=false;
```